# iTunes Connect Updated Contract Where to Accept It?

Tags: itunes

I log into the iTunes connect and get the following message:

```
An updated contract is now available. Before you can offer your content in new iTunes Store territories, a user with the Legal role must agree to the new contract in the Contracts, Tax, and Banking module.
```

I go in the Contracts, Tax and Banking module and I see this (see screenshot). What am I suppose to do?[image]

Comment: Asks how to fill out a form - not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a request next to the new contract, it means the user you logged in with likely does not have the legal role.  Go to manage users and see if your current user has that authorization.  If your current log in does not, you will need to find a user that does, or get yours approved.

Comment: A person with the legal role can only view this above show page.